# Programmatically Simulate a KeyDown Event for RichTextBox in C# 2010

Tags: c#, events, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox on my form, and I want to use the default behavior as the RichTextBox does, such as, Ctrl+Z (Undo) or other actions (Ctrl+Y, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V).

If users use the shortcut keys (Ctrl+Z), it's perfect. But what if the users click a ToolStripButton?

How can I programmatically simulate a KeyDown Event for RichTextBox in C# 2010.

Here is the code snippet that has some issues.  Can you help me on how to Simulate/RaiseEvent in C#?

```
private void tsbUndo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rtbxContent_KeyDown(rtbxContent, new KeyEventArgs(Keys.Control | Keys.Z));
}

private void tsbPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DoPaste();
}

private void DoPaste()
{
    rtbxContent.Paste(DataFormats.GetFormat(DataFormats.UnicodeText));
}

private void rtbxContent_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    //if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control)
    if (e.Control)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            // I want my application use my user-defined behavior as DoPaste() does
            case Keys.V:
                DoPaste();
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                break;

            // I want my application use the default behavior as the RichTextBox control does
            case Keys.A:
            case Keys.X:
            case Keys.C:
            case Keys.Z:
            case Keys.Y:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = false;
                break;

            default:
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` has an [`Undo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.undo.aspx) method that will do the same thing as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>. You can call that when clicking the `ToolStribButton`. There are also `Copy` and `Paste` methods along with a `CanPaste` method that can be used for enabling/disabling the `ToolStripButton` corresponding to the paste command.

This way you don't need to simulate anything but instead call the functionality that produces the behavior. After all, the key presses are just triggers for that behavior.

Comment: Hi Fredrik, you are right that there are corresponding methods doing what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this can actually be done without writing a custom RichTextBox. Instead of calling the Paste() method on the RichTextBox, you can use the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) class, which WILL trigger the key events for a control

```
private void DoPaste()
{
    rtbxContent.Focus(); // You should check to make sure the Caret is in the right place
    SendKeys.Send("^V"); // ^ represents CTRL, V represents the 'V' key
}
```

This of course assumes your data is stored in the Clipboard.

Comment: Hi David, your solution is also perfect for me.  It's a pity that I could not mark two correct answers. SendKeys.Send("^V"); quite useful :-)